# Handle InputMismatchException exception but doesn't catch it Java

Tags: java, exception, integer, try-catch, java.util.scanner

For some unknown reason, when the user input is a string or special characters it doesn't catch my exception (the scanner accepts only integers and from 1 to 3). The code is the below:

```java
package mainpackage;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreateUsers {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner chooseNumber = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;
        
        System.out.println("Welcome to UniStudents Application!\n"
                + "Please select how to Log in: \n"
                + "1. Log in as a Student \n"
                + "2. Log in as a Professor \n"
                + "3. Log in as a Secretary \n"
                + "To choose an action, please write the number of the action: ");  
        number = chooseNumber.nextInt();
        
        while(true) {
            if(number > 3 || number < 1) {
                System.out.println("The number of the action does not exist.\n"
                        +"Please try again: ");
                chooseNumber.nextInt();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("ok");
                chooseNumber.close();
                break;
            }   
        }
        try{
            chooseNumber.nextInt();
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e) {
             
            System.out.println("Please write the number of the action you want to choose \n"
                    + "Please select how to Log in: \n"
                    + "1. Log in as a Student \n"
                    + "2. Log in as a Professor\n"
                    + "3. Log in as a Secretary\n");
        }
```

The result of the code is that:

```
1. Log in as a Student 
2. Log in as a Professor 
3. Log in as a Secretary 
To choose an action, please write the number of the action: 
$^&*
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at JavaBasics/mainpackage.CreateUsers.main(CreateUsers.java:18)
```

I can't figure it out

Comment: In addition to not surrounding the first `number = chooseNumber.nextInt();` by the try/catch exception handling, you are also not saving the result of the 2nd instance, so the loop can never exit.

Answer (score 1):

The first call to `number = chooseNumber.nextInt();` is not in the `try` block, so the exception isn't caught. Move the beginning of the `try` block above it and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Because this exception is thrown at line 18, which is `number = chooseNumber.nextInt();` above `while (true)`, and it is not covered by the try-catch block, try:

```java
package mainpackage;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreateUsers {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner chooseNumber = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;
        
        System.out.println("Welcome to UniStudents Application!\n"
                + "Please select how to Log in: \n"
                + "1. Log in as a Student \n"
                + "2. Log in as a Professor \n"
                + "3. Log in as a Secretary \n"
                + "To choose an action, please write the number of the action: ");  
        try {
            number = chooseNumber.nextInt();
        
            while(true) {
                if(number > 3 || number < 1) {
                    System.out.println("The number of the action does not exist.\n"
                            +"Please try again: ");
                    chooseNumber.nextInt();
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("ok");
                    chooseNumber.close();
                    break;
                }   
            }
            chooseNumber.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
             
            System.out.println("Please write the number of the action you want to choose \n"
                    + "Please select how to Log in: \n"
                    + "1. Log in as a Student \n"
                    + "2. Log in as a Professor\n"
                    + "3. Log in as a Secretary\n");
        }
```